Как обойти ошибку сервера Telegram при использовании метода answer_photo?
Использую следующий код для вывода текста через inline кнопку
@dp.callback_query(F.data == 'bt21')
async def process_button_1_press(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.edit_text(text='<b>Текст</b>', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard8, parse_mode='html')

Но если я хочу использовать другой метод, например answer_photo и вывести изображение вместе с текстом, то я полагаю, что не работает аргумент reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard8:
@dp.callback_query(F.data == 'bt21')
async def process_button_1_press(callback: CallbackQuery):
    photo = FSInputFile("monitoring.jpg")
    await callback.message.answer_photo(photo=photo, caption="Текст", reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard8)

Выводится следующая ошибка при нажатии на inline кнопку:
Telegram server says - Bad Request: there is no text in the message to edit
Странно, так как я с callback_query передаю совершено другую клавиатуру, ну т.е. я не пытаюсь что то отредактировать. Что я упускаю?...

Сдался. Нельзя редактировать edit_text посредством edit_media, который я пробовал вместо answer_photo.
